# How to show a header for LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

this is my lls:

```
 <phone:LongListSelector Name="lls" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Red"  Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="this is a footer"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

and the ViewModel:

```
public class BookViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != title)
            {
                title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AuthorViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

in navigatedto I get and assign DataContext of page:

```
DataContext = book;
```

But the problem, nothing is shown as header in LongListSelector. just right after assigning DataContext I checked and Title has a value but nothing appears (items works fine and a list of items appears)

Why header is empty? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ListHeader` instead of `ListHeaderTemplate` for binding:

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Red"  Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
</phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

[LongListSelector control on Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-longlistselector-control) and  [How to display data in a grouped list in LongListSelector for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) has good example about how to use longlist selector. this will really helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use it, the question is how to solve this unknown problem.

Comment: <phone:LongListSelector Name="lls" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsGroupingEnabled="true" >

Comment: I want a header for list :)

Answer (score 0):

Set ElementName for LongListSelector and Path for DataContext of your ListHeader.

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{ElementName=lls,
               Path=DataContext.Title}" Foreground="Red"  Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
```